# jquery select return both options when click not the most recent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My question may sound a little confusing, but I hope after reading this it will be a little more clear.

html

```
<form id="form">
selected: <input type="text" name="opt" id="opt">
<ul id="list">
<li>car</li>
<li>bus</li>
<li>bike</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    var id= $(this).text();
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

When I click a list-item and then click another list-item before clicking submit, it alerts one after the other, for e.g. if I click car then bike, it alerts bike then it flashes and then alerts car. The aim is to only have it alert the final click, or in other words the one that is the chosen option. So instead of alerting on each click, I want it to alert bike since that was the final option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/RFgYk/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/RFgYk/

**code**

```
$('#list li').click(function() {
    id = $(this).text();

});

$('#form').submit(function() {
    alert(id);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    id = $('#list li.selected').text();
    alert(id);
});
```

Here, you alert only the last one.

Comment: `:)` just a note bruv: OP uses `this` to identify the currently clicked `li`.

Comment: No, because he never adds that class to the item. If you mean [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), also no -- this is a simple `ul`, not an actual form element.

Answer (score 0):

Each click will submit the form. as per your code. So each click will run the alert as well. Why not use an actual  tag? Curious on what you are hoping to do. Also you could split the form submit out of the click function and store the list value in a global Var

Comment: Hiya, I concur with you, I reckon its a minor mistake in how the `submit` is getting bind-ed `:)`

Comment: Each will click will call `.submit()`, but that usage of the `.submit()` method isn't a trigger but binding a handler to the submit action (i.e. when the form is submitted, do the specified action). Of course it will still do each of the actions when it is submitted, so it's still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a submit handler every time you click an `li` so for each click you will get an alert for the respective `li` from the created submit handler, you should set the submit handler once somewhere outside the click handler.

You can set the value of the last clicked item in the click handler and retrieve it in the submit handler, e.g.

```
$('#list li').click(function() {
    $('#form'.data('last', $(this).text());

});

$('#form').submit(function() {
    alert($('#form'.data('last');
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/m29Qn/)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using classes; also, I assume that the text-box labelled "selected" is expected to display the value of the selected item -- in which case you can use its final value in your alert:

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    $('#opt').val($(this).text());
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#list li').not(this).removeClass('selected');
});

$('#form').submit(function(){
    //To use selected item do: $('#list li.selected')

    alert( $('#opt').val() );
});
```